# RTCAudioSession shows MicrophoneBuiltIn as Input Port though the Bluetooth Device is connected in iOS

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, avaudiosession, avaudiosessioncategory

My iPhone is connected to a Bluetooth Device. I am trying to validate using CBCentral Manager and it says the bluetooth is powered on. But I still see the available inputs as MicrophoneBuiltIn in the current **AVAudioSession**. I need my device to route the Audio to the connected Bluetooth Device. But the current inputs show only **MicrophoneBuiltIn** as option. I am not able to set the preferred Input as **AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP**. Please help me out.